# ADT getting crashed frequently

Tags: java, adt, fedora

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fbfff58a061, pid=4562, tid=140465537804032 
>   JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build
>   1.7.0_51-b13)   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed    oops)   Problematic frame:  C 
>   [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x70061]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11   Failed
>   to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core
>   dumping, try     "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again   An
>   error report file with more information is saved as:
>   /root/hs_err_pid4562.log   If you would like to submit a bug report,
>   please visit:
>       http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp    The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
>       See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

Help me how can i do i resolve this issue?

Comment: Anything else on the machine crashing, or just Java?

Comment: just adt nothing else

Comment: adt lasts for maximum 5 mins not a second more than that

Comment: Sounds like it may have corrupted files. Reinstall. (And use RPM to verify the libsoup package.)

Comment: what commands should i use to verify

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what was wrong but i *completely removed* ***adt eclipse and jdk*** and again *reinstalled* all the **latest versions** and yes i *increased* my **RAM** from **4Gb** to ***8Gb*** and it works fine as of now !